# Can a single ELB classic (CLB) load balancer direct traffic evenly to multiple auto scaling groups?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-elb, kops

I have a hard requirement to use a single ELB Classic (CLB) load balancer. Can a single ELB Classic (CLB) distribute traffic between two different Auto Scaling Groups, both running the same application code with no special path based routing needed from an ALB (Application Load Balancer).

For example, in a high availability (HA) cluster set-up with KOPS, how does KOPS make it possible to use a single ELB Classic load balancer (as an entry point to the API server) to serve traffic to two different Auto Scaling Groups in different Availability Zones (AZs) each with their own master instances?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that it is possible to associate more than one Autoscaling Group (all with the same application code in it's instances) with the same ELB Classic (CLB). It's just not a common use-case which is why people don't think it can be done.

Answer (score 2):

A single classis ELB cannot have multiple ASGs associated with it, but the newer Application Load Balancer can do this.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Even if I don't need any special path based routing, and both auto scaling groups are running the same application?

Comment: You have to have some mechanism to decide what group of servers to direct traffic to - that can be host name, path, or something else.